# Data insertion issue to Firestore loop

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am a beginner in Kotlin programming. This code is a mode that receives collection data one by one by looping through the list containing the document path.

[image]

```
 fun Community_view(Write_Community_data : ArrayList<String>
                   , Community_id : ArrayList<String>
                   , Community_title : ArrayList<String>){

        for(index in 0..Write_Community_data.size-1) {
                    db.collection("Write_Community")
                    .document(Write_Community_data.get(index))
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->

                        //val Community_title = ArrayList<String>()
                        //val Community_id = ArrayList<String>()
                        Community_title.add(documentSnapshot.get("title").toString())
                        Community_id.add(documentSnapshot.get("id").toString())
                        println("data_1 : " + Community_id.size)
                    }

            println("data_2 : " + Community_id.size)

        }
    println("data_3 : " + Community_id.size)
}
```

I thought data_1 would first go to size-1, then data_2, then data_3, and the logs would be recorded.
However, what caused this code to log the following:

[image]

Could you please explain why these logs are being recorded?
Or is there a way to get the above route data more efficiently?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should be adding a listener to the collection itself, not individual documents? Otherwise you're running into issues with multiple asynchronous calls all returning at different times.

Comment: Also your title here is about insertion but the code you've provided is retrieval?

Comment: Oh, I used this title to insert the searched code as a loop. I'm sorry if I gave you confusion. by the way I didn't understand the first question. Can I insert data if I fix the firestore sync part?

Comment: You're querying multiple documents in a loop at the moment, but what you maybe should be doing is querying the collection. They outline how to do this in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection

Comment: So you basically need the content of each and every document, right? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Thanks for the answer, everyone
What I want is to get only the title and id of the document. Is there any other way to get the entire collection query, not the documentSnapshot like the code above?

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? If not could you please share the solution you found?